# Pass Data from TableViewController to XIB file Without Segues- Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xib

Im new to swift and learning swift 3

Im trying to pass data from table view controller to XIB file . I have list of fruits in my table view controller. On click of that i would like to display fruit name in a label in new XIB controller. I tried below code but it is not showing me any data in XIB vc..please tell me what am I missing here

My TableVC:

```
class FruitsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var fruits = ["Apple", "Apricot", "Banana", "Blueberry", "Cantaloupe", "Cherry",
                  "Clementine", "Coconut", "Cranberry", "Fig", "Grape", "Grapefruit",
                  "Kiwi fruit", "Lemon", "Lime", "Lychee", "Mandarine", "Mango",
                  "Melon", "Nectarine", "Olive", "Orange", "Papaya", "Peach",
                  "Pear", "Pineapple", "Raspberry", "Strawberry"]

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fruits.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = fruits[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let dataToPass = fruits[indexPath.row]
        let detailsVC = ShowDetailsXibViewController(nibName: "ShowDetailsXibViewController", bundle: nil)
        detailsVC.dataFromVC = dataToPass
        self.present(ShowDetailsXibViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

Second VC:

```
class ShowDetailsXibViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblFruit: UILabel!

    var dataFromVC : String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        lblFruit.text = dataFromVC
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the ShowDetailsXibViewController method also.

Comment: Thats my full code. Not sure what u meant ShowDetailsXibViewController method..pls lemm know

Comment: Use `present(detailsVC, animated: true)`, namely using the `detailsVC` you previously configured. While we're here, you can lose the unnecessary `self.` reference and `completion` defaults to `nil`, so it can be omitted, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the following line in your code:

```
self.present(ShowDetailsXibViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You instantiate a new instance of ShowDetailsXibViewController there and do not use the one you already created with this line:

```
let detailsVC = ShowDetailsXibViewController(nibName: "ShowDetailsXibViewController", bundle: nil)
```

If you change the first line to the following, it should work:

```
self.present(detailsVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
    self.present(ShowDetailsXibViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here you are creating another `ShowDetailsXibViewController`, which is presented. Instead to present the previously created controller, you should write:

```
    self.present(detailsVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```